# Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем разница между сетевыми картами E1G42ET и E1G42ETBLK?

Tags: сеть, железо

Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем разница между сетевыми картами E1G42ET и E1G42ETBLK? И что подразумевается под Bulk Pack – Order 5, Get 5. А то меня походу в гуле забанили(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что с суффиксом BLK - Bulk Pack. В общем, это, можно сказать, упаковка кучкой. Т.е., насколько я понимаю, просто кинут в пакетик пять штук в отдельных упаковках (если они поштучно вообще пакуют, бывает даже без пакетика приходят). А "Order 5, Get 5" означает, что никаких преференций за опт нету, т.е. пять заказали. пять получили. Таким образом, сетевухи одинаковые, просто в BLK их заказывают по пять штук.